# SE-AutoReviewComments привязка к textarea

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, greasemonkey

#### предыстория.

когда-то [существовало дополнение для firefox](https://stackapps.com/q/2116), позволяющее заготовить свой собственный набор типичных комментариев. об этом даже у нас на мете [было упоминание](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1225/178576).

потом в firefox внесли исправления, приведшие к его неработоспособности, но можно было получить ту же функциональность с помощью [greasemonkey-скрипта](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/raw/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js).

потом (примерно в июне прошлого года) в дизайн (как минимум нашего сайта — https://ru.stackoverflow.com) внесли исправление, которое потребовало корректировки скрипта для того, чтобы ссылка «auto» (нажав которую, можно выбрать подходящий текст для вставки в поле ввода) корректно вставлялась в нужное место в диалоге закрытия вопроса:

```
--- autoreviewcomments.user.js.orig 2021-01-14 14:36:47.989240459 +0000
+++ autoreviewcomments.user.js  2021-01-14 14:37:32.227605251 +0000
@@ -862,7 +862,7 @@
      *                     comment should be placed.
      */
     function findClosureElements(where) {
-      var injectNextTo = $(".close-as-off-topic-pane textarea");
+      var injectNextTo = $("#site-specific-comment textarea");
       var placeCommentIn = injectNextTo;
       return [injectNextTo, placeCommentIn];
     }
```

#### сейчас

на днях опять произошла смена дизайна сайта, и ссылка опять перестала отображаться в диалоге закрытия. появляться она должна вот после этого элемента (отображается в диалоге закрытия вопроса после выбора «Специфичная для сообщества причина», затем «Другая причина - добавить комментарий»):

```
<textarea class="s-textarea mt8" name="siteSpecificOtherText"
  placeholder="К примеру: этот вопрос про администрирование и лучше бы подошёл для Serverfault Stack Exchange.">
  Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что 
</textarea>
```

по аналогии с предыдущим исправлением я попробовал заменить `.close-as-off-topic-pane` на `.s-textarea`, но, видимо, этого недостаточно: ссылка «auto» не появляется.

какие ещё изменения надо внести в скрипт ([повторяю прямую ссылку](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/raw/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js)), чтобы в диалоге закрытия появлялась кнопка «auto», которая должна вставляться туда этим скриптом?

p.s. думаю, излишне вставлять сюда весь текст скрипта. надо бы ограничиться какими-то ключевыми моментами, но моих познаний в javascript недостаточно для вычленения этих моментов. надеюсь, что специалисты помогут и внесут соответствующие правки в текст вопроса.

Comment: может быть, надо больше html-а привести из диалога закрытия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверял на **enso**, должно сработать и здесь (надеюсь...)

```
@@ -826,7 +826,7 @@
     }
     attachAutoLinkInjector(".js-add-link", findCommentElements, injectAutoLink, autoLinkAction);
     attachAutoLinkInjector(".edit-post", findEditSummaryElements, injectAutoLinkEdit, autoLinkAction);
-    attachAutoLinkInjector(".close-question-link", findClosureElements, injectAutoLinkClosure, autoLinkAction);
+    attachAutoLinkInjector(".js-close-question-link", findClosureElements, injectAutoLinkClosure, autoLinkAction);
     attachAutoLinkInjector(".review-actions input:first", findReviewQueueElements, injectAutoLinkReviewQueue, autoLinkAction);
 
     /**
@@ -860,7 +860,7 @@
      *                     comment should be placed.
      */
     function findClosureElements(where) {
-      var injectNextTo = $(".close-as-off-topic-pane textarea");
+      var injectNextTo = $("#site-specific-comment textarea");
       var placeCommentIn = injectNextTo;
       return [injectNextTo, placeCommentIn];
     }
```

Comment: спасибо! обновил упоминание на нашей мете и добавил комментарий [на slackapps](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/75085)

Answer (score 0):

после очередного [обновления дизайна, произошедшего на нашем сайте 23 февраля 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/298597), обсуждаемый диалог стал появляться **ниже** (в третьем измерении) стандартного диалога указания причины закрытия (т.е. стандартный диалог его перекрывает).

у стандартного диалога: `z-index: 9000 !important`.

у обсуждаемого диалога (для выбора собственной причины) свойства `z-index` вообще не наблюдается.

---

добавил в [строку](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/blob/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js#L133) с определением переменной `ccsTemplate`:

```
var cssTemplate = '<style>.auto-review-comments.popup{position:absolute;display:block;width:690px;padding:15px 15px 10px}.auto-review-comments.popup ...
```

свойство `z-index:10000`:

```
var cssTemplate = '<style>.auto-review-comments.popup{position:absolute;display:block;width:690px;padding:15px 15px 10px;z-index:10000}.auto-review-comments.popup ...
```